# Multiple file uploads via Javascript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Is there a way to select more than one files to upload when a user clicks the 'Browse' button, and have those files uploaded without refreshing the page?

This happens in Gmail, when you click to attach a file you can hold down CTRL and select multiple files.

Comment: What do you get returned from the file select dialog? If it's a collection (or some sort of delimited list, you can transform into a collection) you can iterate through it generating multiple requests.

Comment: Gmail uses flash. I don't think this is possible with the standard Html file select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced a similar problem. We had been using Uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) to do uploads. I wrote a blog post on how to use Uploadify to perform multiple file uploads:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2011/03/upload-multiple-files-with-progress-using-uploadify/

There are a couple of supported options:

- Use a single 'input' element and select multiple files.
- Use multiple 'input' elements to select a single file each.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Is there any way to keep that queue list with progress bars from appearing? Instead of that I want to implement my own queue list. I think I do that using the OnSelect event, but how to keep the default queue list from appearing?

Comment: Those appear to be wrapped in a div with the following class 'uploadifyQueue'. You may be able to add a display:none style to that class. I haven't tried this.

Comment: Using the Jquery console in Chrome, setting the display to none works on hiding that queue.. thanks! Should most likely work live too. I'll give it a try

Comment: Feel free to post this to my other question too and I'll accept in both places if this works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553226/ajax-based-file-uploads

Answer (score 1):

there are only two ways of uploading a file without refreshing the page:

1. iframe
2. flash - it will give you the possibility to select multiple files at once

look at [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Check http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ it's a neat plugin!

EDIT: Added an exclamation point.

Comment: Nice [copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553226/ajax-based-file-uploads/5553261#5553261) - at least modify the sentence or anything.

Comment: I am.  =P  Valums was a super secret plugin that only you knew about.

Comment: i said at least you should modify my sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some that is really cross-platform use: [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) it support HTML4, 5, Flash, and much more...